# Google Maps API V3: search markers

Tags: google-maps, search

I am building a google map for a client and they want to be able to search for the markers that I have already added to the map.

I have already built the V3 API map that takes the markers from a MySQL table and pushes them into a marker array, but I am struggling to set up a search box that will list out any matches to the search query.

Anyone had any experience of this or able to help me?

Comment: I'd also like to find a solution to this - have you come up with anything yet?

Comment: Any luck yet? Facing the same problem.

Comment: still no answer for this?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer as well.

Comment: No code downvote.

Comment: Could you please add some code, it will help to determine the best approach to the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would be best served by maintaining your own dataset of pins that have been pulled from the database and handling the searching of them in your own code.  To implement you would need to save the reference to the pin you are creating for each location in that dataset.  So get the locations from the DB, save locally, add them to the map, update the local datastore with the reference to the created pin, then hook your search to your dataset, and finally center or whatever you want to happen on the map pin reference you have saved for that result.

This google walkthrough is a good overview of this type of solution.
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1#creating-the-table

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to visit the following link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: The question is in relation to pins added to the map by the developer. Not searching places or POIs from Google.

Answer (score 0):

For a node.js backend server here is the solution to find the elements if you have already registered the data into the database.

1. First, we created a new POST request handler for URLs with the
   suffix /query. This handler expects a JSON or an array for mysql database request body, which
   specifies three parameters: latitude, longitude, and distance. These
   parameters are then converted and stored as variables in the
   handler.
2. We then created a generic Mongoose Query using the Query Builder
   format. This format begins by establishing a generic query object
   equal to the unfiltered search of all users in our database.
3. If a distance is provided, the Query Builder will add a new search
   condition that filters for all users that fall within the distance
   provided of the query’s coordinates (latitude, longitude). *

*Here
    we can also use the MongoDB search parameter $near and its associated
    properties maxDistance and spherical to specify the range we’re
    looking to cover. We’re multiplying the distance of our query body
    by 1609.34, because we want to take our users’ input (in miles) and
    convert it into the units MongoDB expects (in meters).(For  mongoDB users)

4. Lastly, we’re specifying that the distance should be determined
   assuming a spherical surface. This is important, because we’ll be
   evaluating distances across the globe, as opposed to a flat
   Euclidean surface.
5. Finally, we used query.exec to instruct Mongoose to run the final
   query. If the query encounters no errors, it will provide a JSON
   output of all users who meet the criteria.

   // Retrieves JSON or the array records for all users who meet a certain set of query conditions
   app.post('/query/', function(req, res){

   ```
   // Grab all of the query parameters from the body.
   var lat             = req.body.latitude;
   var long            = req.body.longitude;
   var distance        = req.body.distance;

   // Opens a generic Mongoose Query. Depending on the post body we will...
   var query = User.find({});

   // ...include filter by Max Distance (converting miles to meters)
   if(distance){

       // (optional)Using MongoDB's geospatial querying features. (Note how coordinates are set [long, lat]
       query = query.where('location').near({ center: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}, OR Your own query to be specified here.

           // Converting meters to miles(For mongoDB users). Specifying spherical geometry (for globe)
           maxDistance: distance * 1609.34, spherical: true});
   }

   // ... Other queries will go here ... 

   // Execute Query and Return the Query Results
   query.exec(function(err, users){
       if(err)
           res.send(err);

       // If no errors, respond with a JSON of all users that meet the criteria or you can also enter the array number you want to pass.
       res.json(users);
   });
   ```

   });

You can also read about [geojson](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/) or refer to this Google Map project using MEAN stack.